# cache.get slower from server than within Django shell

Tags: python, django, caching

For some reason, the cache is **much** slower from the web server than from within the normal shell. In the shell, average is around ~0.2 ms while for the web server it averages around 15 ms. It doesn't matter if I'm using the built-in cache or if I use memcached, the time difference is approximately the same.

Here's the code I'm using to test the discrepancy:

```
def test_cache_time():
    from django.core.cache import cache
    import time
    for _ in range(20):
        start, _, end = time.time(), cache.get('random-key-name'), time.time()
        cache_times.append((end - start) * 1000)
    return max(cache_times), min(cache_times), sum(cache_times)/len(cache_times)


def debug_view(request, …):
    max_tct, min_tct, avg_tct = test_cache_time()
    messages.info(request, "cache.get took %.2f ms (max %.2f, min %.2f)" % (avg_tct, max_tct, min_tct))
    ...
```

When I view it from the web page:

> cache.get took 14.92 ms (max 52.33, min 5.96)

Then in the shell:

```
>>> from conferences import views
>>> views.test_cache_time()
(15.92397689819336, 0.11777877807617188, 0.9135127067565918)
>>>
```

I'm just trying to figure out what could possibly cause such a big difference in times. At this point, the performance hit for get.cache is such that it's basically making my web pages come to a crawl.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that when django-debug-toolbar is running it results in a fairly significant performance hit on cache requests.

Once debug toolbar was disabled the time difference went away.

Answer (score 0):

You measured two different things. Execute the cache 100 times in debug view too.

Maybe the first call has some warmup and the other calls are faster.

Comment: I've amended the code. The difference is still there but I figured out why.